# Ubuntu 14.04 termial : hub 4-6 cannot enable port 3. maybe usb cable is bad

Tags: 14.04

I am gettin this message in ubuntu termial and I do not know how to make it stop, since I cannnot use the terminal with this error?
any one knows why and I can I solve this?

Comment: What device do you have plugged into that port? Look at the output of `lsusb`.  Maybe there is some problem with the device.

Comment: First I thought it was the printer since it was not detecting it anymore, but after remove it the problem was still there and the only device plugged were the keyboard and the mouse (both working)

Comment: Check what is plugged into that port with `ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-6.3/`. You could also `ssh` in remotely and unplug the keyboard and mouse and see if you still get the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like either one of your USB ports is bad, or, like it says, the cable is bad. try moving your USB devices to different ports and try different cables. Try removing everything USB and only using your USB Keyboard/Mouse. You will need to keep moving the USBs to different ports until, through Trial and Error, you figure out which USB port/USB cable is giving you the error. Then either stop using that USB port or get a new Cable, which ever the case may be.

Hope this helps!

Edit HUB 4-6 port 3 means USB plug #6, if that narrows it down for you at all..

Comment: I already tried moving and removing, and also I changed the cable but nothing happens

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your hardware then.

Comment: I changed the used USB port and it worked